# HDFS Federation Unknown Namespace

Tags: hadoop

Let's say that I have configured two name nodes to manage /marketing and /finance respectively. I am wondering what is going to be happened if I were to put a file in /accounting directory. Would HDFS accept the file? If so, which namespace manages the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The write will fail.  Neither namespace will manage the file.

You will get an `IOException` with a `No such file or directory` error from the `ViewFs` client.

For example, given the following ViewFs config in `core-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>viewfs:///</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.viewfs.mounttable.default.link./namenode-a</name>
        <value>hdfs://namenode-a</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.viewfs.mounttable.default.link./namenode-b</name>
        <value>hdfs://namenode-b</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

The following behavior is exhibited:

```
$ bin/hdfs dfs -ls /
-r--r--r--   - sirianni gopher          0 2013-10-22 15:58 /namenode-a
-r--r--r--   - sirianni gopher          0 2013-10-22 15:58 /namenode-b


$ bin/hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/bar.txt /foo/bar.txt
copyFromLocal: `/foo/bar.txt': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I have a question, the Client can't write a file outside the existing namespaces in hdfs federation?