# read file from hdfs federation

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

If I set up the Hadoop cluster using NameNode Federation.NameNode1 manages the /marketing namespace and one NameNode2 manages the /sales namespace.
When client tries to write a file to/reports/myreport.txt, the file successfully writes to /report/myreport.txt. The metadata for the file is managed by the 
first NameNode to which the client connects (NameNode2 for example).
So when client tries to read a file /reports/myreport.txt, How does the data get from the DataNodes to the client? Which the namenode responsible?

Comment: You first introduce /marketing and /sales but then don't refer to them. How does /report relate to this introduction?

Comment: I want to say that the client want to read a file outside the existing namespaces.

Comment: Are you sure you were able to write or are you assuming. check this out, looks like the write would fail with IOException http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344036/hdfs-federation-unknown-namespace

Comment: So the Client can't write a file to /reports/myreport.txt  in hdfs federation?